# Which one is correct: "in my previous job" or "at my previous job"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which one is correct: *in my previous job* or *at my previous job*? For example:

> **At** my previous job, I taught adults and children.
>
> **In** my previous job, I taught adults and children.

I was reading a book in which the author, native speaker of English, used *at my previous job*. I have never seen *at my previous job* being used. So I asked a friend of mine, who is also a native speaker of English. She told me that *at my previous job* sounds wrong to her. That made me wonder which one is standard English. If both are fine, is there a nuance of meaning between them?

Comment: If the main clause is about your duties, *at* may be more common but *in* is more specific.  For any other work-related subject, such as the physical or social environment or the structure of the organization, say *at*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is based on the research I did online, like the OP and perhaps many a native speaker, I feel that "in" sounds more natural. However, websites, newsmagazines and Google Ngrams clearly demonstrate that both versions are used by competent native speakers and are therefore grammatical.

#### at my [old job]

- “[**At my previous job**](https://www.livecareer.com/resources/interviews/questions/what-will-you-miss-about-your-present-last-job) I was able to form strong relationships with my colleagues. By working together we benefited the company and our customers.”
- My job history demonstrates that I have ample experience writing, editing, and submitting press releases. I have written press releases as part of my duties **[at my two previous jobs](https://nancyvanleuven.com/for-students/top-5-job-interview-questions-and-how-to-answer/)**, and I am glad to provide you with writing samples.
- I have a special interest in inflammatory bowel disease, nutrition and endoscopy. I was clinical lead for IBD and nutrition **[at my previous employment](https://www.royalwolverhampton.nhs.uk/services/service-directory-a-z/gastroenterology/endoscopy/meet-the-team/dr-ashit-shah/)**. I also have an interest in medical education and during my postgraduate training undertook a clinical teaching fellow post at University Hospital Coventry and Warwick.
- I have an employee who has worked for us two years now. She is constantly starting a ton of sentences with the words “[**at my last job**](https://www.askamanager.org/2018/10/my-employee-keeps-saying-at-my-last-job-we-did-it-a-different-way.html)…” This is becoming a huge annoyance to many people.
- After four years of college, I make $1,000 less than I did [**at my old job**](https://books.google.it/books?id=HcgiVszahP0C&q=%22At%20my%20old%20job%22&dq=%22At%20my%20old%20job%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitrIe5h8nsAhWzQUEAHVLEAbcQ6AEwCXoECAsQAg). ... I am much worse off now.
- I’ve been [**at my new job**](https://www.indeed.com/community/career-path/should-i-go-back-to-my-old-job/td-p/2170380) for a month now. I was at my previous job for 2 and a half years.

#### in my [old job]

- Politicians, she said, are expected to "repeat the same things pretty often. **[In my previous job](https://books.google.it/books?id=FJfLtLnhZkYC&pg=PT8&dq=%22in%20my%20previous%20job%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ29m_k8nsAhWdQEEAHSBVBvc4FBDoATABegQIAxAC#v=onepage&q=%22in%20my%20previous%20job%22&f=false)** as a physicist, that was a mortal sin. In science, the task is never to tell the same thing twice” because it would indicate “that you haven't done anything all day.”
- **[In my previous position](https://www.thriveyard.com/57-common-interview-questions-answers-and-examples/)** as a Regional Sales Manager, I had an intensive international travel schedule of about 60% of my job.
- “**[In my previous employment](https://www.wikijob.co.uk/content/interview-advice/interview-preparation/how-best-use-star-technique-interview-questions)** at Aldi, it was my job to replace all of the previous stock by restacking the shelves.
  This was stock which had reached its best-before-date and so was going to be thrown out by the supermarket.”
- **[In my old job](https://books.google.it/books?id=c9ypIsKyR2MC&pg=PA64&dq=%22in%20my%20old%20job%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqlsS7lMnsAhVNilwKHV42A6wQ6AEwCHoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22in%20my%20old%20job%22&f=false)** I brought clients who did a certain amount of business down here, and I'd give them a free hunt. I decided that was more fun than selling surveying equipment.”
- One of my key strengths is my ability to deal with customers in a professional and sensitive manner. This is something I demonstrated **[in my last job](https://books.google.it/books?id=8bkKoNijP8wC&pg=PA68&dq=%22in%20my%20last%20job%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjth7GzlcnsAhXRbsAKHYioB50Q6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22in%20my%20last%20job%22&f=false)** where I was able to process customer returns efficiently and quickly and this was commented on by my supervisor in my annual appraisal.
- “**In my last job** before I quit work to trade, I was the project leader on this team that was responsible for making sure that our 500 worldwide servers were able to function,” Hamilton says.

Ngram:  "in my old job" (blue line) vs "at my old job" (red line)

[image]

"in my last job" (in blue) vs "at my last job" (in red)

[image]

“in my previous job” (blue) vs “at my previous job” (red)

[image]

These are the results from Google Ngram comparing the aforementioned phrases in the same chart

[image]

In the American English Ngram chart below, the phrases "**at my old job**" and "**at my last job**" have a much higher number of incidences (0.000000450%) compared to the versions with *in* (between 0.000000300% and 0.000000350%). However, since 2015 the margin of difference between  *at* and *in* has decreased sharply when they precede the more formal phrase “my previous job”.

[image]

In the following examples, the prepositions *at* and *in* are interchangeable and there is no significant change in meaning.

1. That's why Jonathan Israel, who has been on his new job as a research manager at Ipsos for three months, checks on his company's Web site for employees' pictures, names and titles. **[At his previous job](https://www.forbes.com/2006/10/24/leadership-careers-jobs-lead-careers-cx_tw_1024bizbasics.html#74e5f52b168e)**, he even printed out a cheat sheet and kept it in a drawer.
2. Ariel Seidman, Gigwalk's CEO and co-founder, said his new company grew out of frustration. **[At his previous job](https://abcnews.go.com/Technology/gigwalk-mobile-app-pays-taking-iphone-pictures-collecting/story?id=13539488)** at Yahoo, he said everyone told him it would be impossible to collect useful amounts of local data.
3. She still travels up to three months a year, though that's better than the six months a year spent on the road **[at her previous job](https://www.newsweek.com/americans-may-face-leaner-workplaces-years-75483)**. Overall, Krostoski says she's relieved. "There aren't many jobs in Oregon," she says, noting the state's 11.3 percent unemployment rate. "I [know] folks who have been looking for a job for a year or more."
4. I do have sales experience when you consider that **in my previous job** I was a de facto sales representative for the restaurant.
5. What drove him to this change was the need to develop his human capital. **In my previous job** I had opportunities to do new things and was involved to some extent with the organizational development of the company
6. I am highly flattered that I have been selected for such a prestige job which gives me such great scope. I get 50 percent more salary than I had **in my previous job**.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you are talking about the *role* or the *place of work*. Idiomatically, we do sometimes the word "job" to mean both. You are *in* a role, but *at* a place of work.